# $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and continuous imply $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for some $1\leq p < \infty$ does not imply that $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x)=0$ and I want to know if $f$ is continuous, then $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x)=0$ ?
can you one help me with this question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That isn't even a $L^p$-function.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, you can have a function that has 'spikes' with increasing height but mass that is decreasing fast enough. Something along the following lines.

Let $\varphi$ be the classical bump function $\varphi(x) = e^{\frac{1}{x^2 − 1}}$ for $\vert x \vert < 1$ und $\varphi(x) = 0$ for $\vert x \vert \geq 1$.

Define $f$ by $f(x) := \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\, k\,\varphi(2^{k} (x - k))}$.
Then $f$ is continuous and in every $L^p$ for $p \in [1, \infty)$, but doesn't decay in a pointwise sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea when $p=1$. You can modify easily to $1 < p < \infty$.

Let $f_k$, $k \ge 1$ be the continuous function that is identically equal to $0$ except on the interval $[k,k+1/k^3]$ where it is piecewise linear and satifies $f_k(k+\frac 12) = k$.  The graph of $f_k$ is a triangle with baselength $1/k^3$ and height $k$ so that $$\int f_k \, dx = \frac 1{2k^2}.$$

Since the "spikes" of the $f_k$ are nonoverlapping the sum $f = \displaystyle f_k$ is also continuous with integral
$$\int f = \sum_k \frac{1}{2k^2} < \infty$$
but $\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$.